# Socket.io clean messages

Tags: javascript

I'm creating an app to manage a website, the website uses socket.io chat so users can communicate, my question is i checked my chrome network request and the socket.io messages are sent to a 'frame' is there any possibility to clean that frame message with javascript, because it keeps logging the messages etc and after like 3h of my app running the memory will increase to 300/400MB and after 10h it will start using 800MB of memory, so is there anyway to clean the socket.io messages on my app side (the site isn't mine so i can't access the socket.io server)

What i want to clean
[image: What i want to clean]

Some headers information (Don't know if needed)
[image]

Comment: This functionality is provided by Chrome Dev tools and has nothing to do with how much memory your application consumes... This is like saying if you click the "Preserve log" button in the "Network" tab it will increase your application memory. If you don't open the Dev tools, nothing is even tracked.

Comment: Since i made the same app in c# with only a firefox browser in it, and opened the chat, after 30mn memory jump from 30MB to 100MB without even touching on the app.

Comment: Something else must be using up your memory. Try profiling your application. Chrome Dev tools also have a tab called "Memory" which can take heap snapshots or/and even monitor it over a period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if you are storing all the received messages in your own code.

Namely, do you end up able to see every single message received since the initial page load. (And maybe your DOM might be fat with many things.)

If so, the memory used from past messages will not be garbage collected. You have to "forget" some of those messages and retrieve them from the server again when they are needed.

Comment: Yes i can see all msgs sent by the server if i check on devtool how can i make my code forget it, when the site is loaded the site has a chat.ini that starts the connection etc and they don't have any function to clean or disconnect how can i do the 'forget' on my app ?